# How to get the entities of an user usign ACL in Symfony

Tags: symfony, acl

I'm trying to create a pretty simple application: I'm using FOS user bundle and ACL.

I have an entitie called Site, the users can create sites. When they do so I assign the use as owner of the site.

Now I'd like to have a page where I list the domains the users owns or he has read permissions. I've been searching but I couldn't find anything to solve it.

Comment: I'd recommend you using security voters instead of ACL. It's way easier understand and much more flexible to use.  Here is a nice source with examples: http://slides.com/marieminasyan/drop-ace-use-role-voters#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you set up a normal entity relation between `user` and `site`? Then you just do `$user->getSites()` or write a custom query and there you get all of this user's sites.

Then for security you can use voters, as stated in the comment above, or you can also just use a security annotation with an expression like `@Security("user.getSites().contains(site)")`.